# pushVC from filtered tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, filter

I added a working SearchBar to my tableView - if I click on a cell from the unfiltered tableView, it get's me to the right second VC (chat controller)... but if I click on a cell from the filtered tableView, I get pushed to the secondVC from the cell of the unfiltered tableView - so if I filter a tableView and click on a cell from the filteredTableView, I actually click on the cell from the unfilteredTableView - I hope you understand my problem...

**If not here is an example:** The unfilteredTableView shows in the third cell the name "Alex3", now when I click on the cell I get to the Chat with "Alex3" - but if I filter the tableView for "John3" and click on the third cell I don't get to the chat with "John3", but to the Chat with "Alex3"

This is the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    searchController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Code for SearchBar/Controller:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering() {
        return filtered.count
    }
    return users.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    var user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
    if isFiltering() {
        user = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        user = users[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.textLabel!.text = user.name

    return cell
}

//UISearchBar
func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
    // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
    return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

func isFiltering() -> Bool {
    return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
}

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filtered = users.filter({( user : User) -> Bool in
        return (user.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
}


}

extension NewMessageController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry if the title is a bit misleading, but I'm new to programming and don't have any special words for what's going on there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to help here if you could share the filtration logic that would be helpful in analysing the issue but from what you have shared I have a suggestion.

```
let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
```

Check if you are fetching the user from filtered list and not the original list. This might help

Please find below sample code this might help

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    searchController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    var user : User?
    if isFiltering() {
        user = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        user = users[indexPath.row]
    }
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the rest of the code, could you may tell me how I can fetch the user from the filtered list?

Comment: @J.Doe I have modified my answer to please have a look at the code. You need to add the filter logic and check in you didSelectRowAt

Comment: nevermind, got it working by deleting the dismiss line, thanks for your help